# jQuery multi-list solution for comparing and saving items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm making a tool, which can compare and list items. I'd like to animate them so that they look cool. Please help me fix some issues in the implementation. There are multiple problems so i made a separate issue of each one.

## issue 1 mouseout event binding

Sometimes the overlay panel closes if I pick an item and pull it to list1 - list2 - list1.

## issue 2 click event binding

If I push an element to list1, drop it to the list and click on the another list, the list will comes closer. On clicking back to list1 it animate 3 times instead of one.

## issue 3 placeholders

How can i drop a placeholder to a list, what makes better re-arrange and easier to understanding the cross-dropping (for list to list drag and drop and items to lists too)

## issue 4 animation smoothness

How can I make the animation go smoother? What do you think about this?

## issue 5 optimalization

What do you think, if I optimize the code a bit will it be faster in the browsers? Could you give me some advices for this please?

## issue 6 other ideas

If you have some general ideas for it, I'll welcome them as well.
Download it, use it as you want, I'm making it for my girlfriend's website.

[You can check the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/qejFh/) - jsFiddle, or:

HTML

```
<div id="overlay" class="clearfix">
    <div id="overlaycontainer">
        <div id="comparecontainer" class="overlaycontainer">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <ul id="compare">
                <li class="fixed">LIST1</li>        
            </ul>
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            
        </div>
        <div id="dreamlistcontainer" class="overlaycontainer">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <ul id="dreamlist">
                <li class="fixed">LIST2</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr />

<ul class="offers clearfix">
    <li name="deal1">ITEM #1</li>
    <li name="deal2">ITEM #2</li>
    <li name="deal3">ITEM #3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body {background-color: white; padding: 50px 0 0; margin: 0;}
ul {list-style-type: none;}
#overlay {background: black url(img/dreamlist_bg.gif) center center no-repeat; display: none; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#overlaycontainer {width: 800px; height: 600px; position: relative; margin: auto; top: 50%; margin-top: -300px;}
.clearfix:after {visibility: hidden;display: block;font-size: 0;content: " ";clear: both;height: 0;}
.overlaycontainer { height:500px; float: left;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.overlaycontainer.active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1cb9ee, 0 0 30px #1a86ce, 0 0 3px white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1cb9ee, 0 0 30px #1a86ce, 0 0 3px white;
}
#compare {padding: 20px; background-color: yellow;}
#dreamlist {padding: 20px; background-color: white;}        
#comparecontainer {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 290px; opacity: 0.9;}
#dreamlistcontainer {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 500px; opacity: 0.9;}
li {padding: 10px;}
.drop {width: 10px; height:10px; background-color: red; display: inline-block;}    
.offers {padding: 10px;}
.offers li {width: 194px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;float: left; margin-right: 5px;}
.fixed {text-transform: uppercase; font-family: "Gill Sans"; color: #1a86ce; font-size: 28px; text-align: center; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px white;}
.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -11px;
    display: block;
    background: transparent url(img/imagesforem.png) no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.icon {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    background: transparent url(img/imagesforic.png) no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#comparecontainer .icon {background-position: bottom left; left: 41%;}
#dreamlistcontainer .icon {background-position: bottom right; right: 50%}
```

JS

```
function overlayFadeIn() {
    $("#overlay").fadeIn();
}

function overlayFadeOut() {
    //    alert("faded.");
    pushBack();
    $("#overlay").fadeOut();
    $("#overlaycontainer").unbind("mouseleave");
}

function dropOut() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
}

function pushBack() {
    $("#overlaycontainer").unbind("mouseleave");
    $("#dreamlist").parent().animate({
        width: "500px",
        opacity: "0.9",
        right: "0",
        top: "0",
        height: "500px"
    }, 100);
    $("#compare").parent().animate({
        width: "290px",
        opacity: "0.9",
        left: "0",
        top: "0",
        height: "500px"
    }, 100);
    $("#overlaycontainer").bind("mouseleave", overlayFadeOut);
}

function pushBitCloser(which) {
    var which = which;
    var other;
    if (which.attr("id") == "dreamlist") {
        other = $("#compare"); //bal - left
        whleft = "+=15px";
        otleft = "+=0px";
        whright = "+=0px";
        otright = "+=50px";
    }
    else {
        other = $("#dreamlist"); // right
        whleft = "+=0px";
        otleft = "-=10px";
        whright = "+=0px";
        otright = "+=0px";
    }


    if (which.attr("id") == "dreamlist") {
        $("#dreamlist").parent().animate({
            width: "530px",
            opacity: "1",
            height: "550px",
            top: "-25px",
            right: "-15px"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                opacity: 'linear'
            }
        });
        $("#compare").parent().animate({
            width: "270px",
            opacity: "0.7",
            left: "+10px",
            top: "+10px",
            height: "480px"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                height: 'linear',
                top: 'linear',
                opacity: 'linear'
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#compare").parent().animate({
            width: "320px",
            opacity: "1",
            left: "+10px",
            top: "-15px",
            height: "530px"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                height: 'linear',
                top: 'linear',
                opacity: 'linear'
            }
        });
        $("#dreamlist").parent().animate({
            width: "470px",
            opacity: "0.7",
            height: "480px",
            top: "+10px",
            right: "-15px"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                opacity: 'linear'
            }
        });

    }
}

function pushCloser(which, pb) {
    if (pb == true) {
        pushBack();
    }

    var which = which;
    var other;
    if (which.attr("id") == "dreamlist") {
        other = $("#compare");
    }
    else {
        other = $("#dreamlist");
    }

    which.parent().css({
        "z-index": "20"
    });
    other.parent().css({
        "z-index": "10"
    });



    if (which.attr("id") == "dreamlist") {
        $("#dreamlist").parent().animate({
            width: "550px",
            opacity: "1",
            height: "550px",
            top: "-25px",
            right: "-15px"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                opacity: 'linear'
            }
        });
        $("#compare").parent().animate({
            width: "270px",
            opacity: "0.7",
            left: "+10px",
            top: "+10px",
            height: "480px"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                height: 'linear',
                top: 'linear',
                opacity: 'linear'
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#compare").parent().animate({
            width: "320px",
            opacity: "1",
            left: "+15px",
            top: "-15px",
            height: "530px"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                height: 'linear',
                top: 'linear',
                opacity: 'linear'
            }
        });
        $("#dreamlist").parent().animate({
            width: "490px",
            opacity: "0.7",
            height: "480px",
            top: "+10px",
            right: "-10px"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                opacity: 'linear'
            }
        });

    }
}

$(".offers li").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: "move",
    zIndex: 30,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        overlayFadeIn();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $("#overlaycontainer").bind("mouseleave", overlayFadeOut);
    }
});

$("#compare").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.incompare)",
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        pushBitCloser($(this));
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        pushBack($(this));

    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        $("#overlaycontainer").bind("mouseleave", overlayFadeOut);

        pushCloser($(this), false);
        var element_id = ui.draggable.attr("name");
        var gotit = $("#compare li[name='" + element_id + "']").size();
        if (gotit != 1) {
            var drop = $('<span></span>').addClass("drop").bind("click", dropOut);
            $('<li class="incompare"></li>').attr("name", element_id).text(ui.draggable.text()).append(drop).appendTo(this);
        }
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        $("#dreamlist").parent().click(function() {
            pushCloser($("#dreamlist"), true)
        });
    }
}).sortable({
    helper: "clone",
    items: "li:not(.placeholder):not(.fixed)",
    start: function() {
        $("#overlaycontainer").unbind("mouseleave");
    },
    stop: function() {
        $("#overlaycontainer").bind("mouseleave", overlayFadeOut);
    },
    sort: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    }
});

$("#dreamlist").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.indreamlist)",
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        pushBitCloser($(this));
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        pushBack($(this));

    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        $("#overlaycontainer").bind("mouseleave", overlayFadeOut);
        pushCloser($(this), false);
        var element_id = ui.draggable.attr("name");
        var gotit = $("#dreamlist li[name='" + element_id + "']").size();
        if (gotit != 1) {
            var drop = $('<span></span>').addClass("drop").bind("click", dropOut);
            $('<li class="indreamlist"></li>').attr("name", element_id).text(ui.draggable.text()).append(drop).appendTo(this);
        }
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        $("#compare").parent().click(function() {
            pushCloser($("#compare"), true)
        });
    }
}).sortable({
    helper: "clone",
    items: "li:not(.placeholder):not(.fixed)",
    start: function() {
        $("#overlaycontainer").unbind("mouseleave");
    },
    stop: function() {
        $("#overlaycontainer").bind("mouseleave", overlayFadeOut);
    },
    sort: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    }
});
```

Comment: tl;dr (Try shorter focussed questions. Those gigantic code dumps and the spray of questions, they're putting folks off. And it's the weekend.)

Comment: @Repas your application is trippy. Either its buggy or its bad UI design.

Comment: I find the animations disturbing and annoying. It's slow and unnatural. +1 for "trippy".

Comment: How can you offer a bounty of 250 when you only have 48 of reputation?

Comment: @Capsule: He used to have 298 before he started the bounty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to reinvent the wheel and over-complicate things all for the sake of what looks sexy but, in reality, is probably going to drive your users nuts.

From our (stackoverflow) end, this is a whole lot of code that is very specific to what you're trying to do but there is simply to much going on for us to look at one area and provide assistance.

Take a look at jQuery Sortable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists.  It's a very clean but good looking example that can certainly be jazzed up with some jQuery CSS animations.  The performance will be very good across all browsers and you'll find it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code (which doesn't look great at all in Chrome) I can't help but think that you're simply trying to reinvent the functionality that jQuery UI multiselect is attempting to address when it's released.  In the mean time, I've used this code quite frequently for sortable, selectable lists...it's SO quick and easy.

http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

As others have said, no reason to reinvent the wheel--go develop the next Facebook and help support the rest of us starving developers.